# jQuery script to toggle an element and handle a Close button

Tags: javascript, performance, beginner, jquery

First of all: I am a total javascript beginner and therefore I am asking you to rate my script and tell me whether its okay or just a big mess. Note: it does work, but I guess it could be improved.

My main goal was to create a script, than can be used multiple times and does not depend on any class or id name (thats why I am using the data attribute).

```
$(function(){
    var toggleOpen      = $('*.[data-toggle="open"]');
    var toggleContent   = $('*.[data-toggle="content"]');
    var toggleClose     = $('*.[data-toggle="close"]');
    var toggleSpeed     = 500;
    //Set height of toggle content to avoid animation jumping
    toggleContent.css('height', toggleContent.height() + 'px');
    //Find content to toggle
    function findNextContent(target){
        var nextContent = target.parent().parent().parent().find(toggleContent);
        return nextContent;
    }
    //Toggle content
    function slideToggle(target){
        target.stop(true,true).slideToggle(toggleSpeed);
    }
    //CLose toggled content
    function closeToggle(target){
        target.slideUp(toggleSpeed);
    }
    //On Open Click
    toggleOpen.click(function(){
        var clicked     = $(this);
        var nextContent = findNextContent(clicked);
        //Check if hidden to either scroll to bottom or not
        if(nextContent.is(':hidden')){
            slideToggle(nextContent);
            smoothScrolling(toggleClose);
        }else{
            slideToggle(nextContent);
        }
        return false;
    });
    //On Close click
    toggleClose.click(function(){
        var clicked     = $(this);
        var nextContent = findNextContent(clicked);
        closeToggle(nextContent);
        return false;
    });
});
```

What it does: It toggles an element and it also takes care of a seperate close button.

I am glad for any feedback - be it positive or negative!

Comment: Before I get started reviewing, have you [linted](http://www.jshint.com/) your code?

Comment: @kojiro No, actually its the first time I heard of this tool and thanks a lot for sharing!! After doing it: I get a couple of "Unnecessary semicolon" (I´d like to keep them though - in case they dont have any negative impact?). And "'smoothScrolling' is not defined." (thats because this function is outside my pasted example, but it does ofc exist in my whole code). Thanks again for sharing that tool!

Comment: Oh and one more thing: "Line 3: var toggleOpen = $('*.[data-toggle="open"]'); Missing "use strict" statement." I am not sure what this means and how to solve it...

Comment: `"use strict"` is a feature of newer versions of JS.  It means to make sure you're not doing a bunch of stuff that people accidentally do that causes lots of headaches.  To use it, basically, you put that string (*just* that string; no var, no whatever=, none of that.  just `"use strict";`) as the first line of your function, and then fix all the errors you'll probably get.  :)

Comment: [Here's some information on strict mode.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1335851) If you decide not to use it, you can turn it off in the [linter's options](http://www.jshint.com/options/). Get rid of the extra semicolons and read about the [difference between function declarations and function expressions.](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/) As for `smoothScrolling`, you can just tell the linter that it's a global, and it won't complain anymore.

Comment: @cHao: Thanks for the explanation. So would you suggest to basically always use it in every script by putting it on top of any .js file?

Comment: @Andrej: If you like the idea of saying "hey, JavaScript, help me write better code", then try it out.  Personally, i don't use it...but i can see where it might provide some huge benefits (assuming it's watching for actual common flaws and not just style issues).

Comment: @kojiro: Following your advices, I have eliminated all errors and warnings and Lint gives me a "Good Job" :) - but this doesnt mean the script is well-written and efficient, does it?

Comment: @Andrej it means your script is lint-free and that if there are logic errors or other problems they'll be easier to pick out. So now, update your above code to the lint-free version.

Comment: @kojiro: Did that! Thanks for all your support.

Comment: What does the `*.` part do in those first three selectors?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: Thanks for your input! I initially thought it might be a good idea to add it to target all elements, which have the data attribute. But due to your comment and after testing it, I removed it now, because it works just fine for all elements without `*.`

Comment: @Andrej I thought that may be the case but I was confused how `.[attr]` actually selected anything at all, unless it was a special character somehow (it's normally used for class selection). So yes, `[attr]` is the same as `*[attr]` - or in the more general sense: `*` is only necessary when alone and not combined with any other selectors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
function findNextContent(target){
    var nextContent = target.parent().parent().parent().find(toggleContent);
    return nextContent;
}
```

You could possibly use the jQuery [closest](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) function here.
Or you could remove the variable and just do `return target.parent().parent().parent().find(toggleContent);`

```
toggleClose.click(function(){
    var clicked     = $(this);
    var nextContent = findNextContent(clicked);
    closeToggle(nextContent);
    return false;
});
```

There is no need for the `clicked` variable. You can just write `findNextContent($(this));`

You might also want to look into the [aria-expanded](http://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/states_and_properties#aria-expanded) attribute.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the improvements! I am gonna use `closest()` (edit: I ended up using `parents()` instead of `closest()`), since it makes more sense and I will remove the `var nextContent`. About the `clicked` variable: i thought that I maybe need to use `$(this)` more than once (not at the moment, but maybe when I expand the script with some more functionality) and I have read somewhere that when using it or any other selector more than once or twice, its a good idea to save it as a variable (not sure if thats true?). Thanks again!

Comment: For some reason `target.closest(toggleContent);` doesnt work, but `target.parents().find(toggleContent);` does. I would like to use closest() though, because it would not return multiple elements (if there are more than one). I will try to find the problem and post the edit in my original question!

Comment: Great! As for the $(this), it is indeed better to cache it if you intend to use it multiple times. However, you can just do that when (and if) you expand the script.

Comment: @Andrej I agree With DADU, I think the saying is: "Premature Optimisation is the root of all evil."

Comment: @James That's correct. A trap I've been fallen into too many times (I can sense if from far now).

Comment: @JamesKhoury: That really helped a lot! I didnt look at it from your point of view and was thinking "I am probably gonna need it". But thinking about it again, you are totally right to not use it until I actually need it. A great lesson to keep in mind for all future projects.

Answer (score 2):

OK, this code looks fine to me. The only thing I can suggest is that you might prefer to use `event.preventDefault` instead of `return false` in your event handlers, because in jQuery, `return false` in an event handler causes both event.preventDefault() *and* `event.stopPropagation()`, which you may not want.

References:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1357118/javascript-event-preventdefault-vs-return-false
- http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/

Comment: Thanks again for the time you spent to look into it! I will go  with `event.preventDefault`